# Cannot show notifications with Broadcast Receiver Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, notifications, broadcastreceiver, xamarin.android

I want to show a reminder (notification and alarm) when a button is clicked on my app. I have created a BroadcastReceiver to create the notification. This is called when I click a button in my fragment.

Here is what I have done so far:-

```
public class AlarmReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
    {
        private int resourceId;
        public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {
            var message = intent.GetStringExtra("message");
            var title = intent.GetStringExtra("title");
            var mEvent = intent.GetStringExtra("event");

            var notIntent = new Intent(context, typeof(SplashActivity));
            var contentIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(context, 0, notIntent, PendingIntentFlags.CancelCurrent);
            var manager = NotificationManagerCompat.From(context);

            var style = new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle();
            style.BigText(message);


            if (mEvent == "Birthday")
                resourceId = Resource.Drawable.ic_cupcake;
            else if (mEvent== "Anniversary")
                resourceId = Resource.Drawable.ic_anniversary;


            var wearableExtender = new NotificationCompat.WearableExtender().SetBackground(BitmapFactory.DecodeResource(context.Resources, resourceId));

            //Generate a notification with just short text and small icon
            var builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                            .SetContentIntent(contentIntent)
                            .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.ic_applogo)
                            .SetContentTitle(title)
                            .SetContentText(message)
                            .SetDefaults(1)
                            .SetStyle(style)
                            .SetWhen(Java.Lang.JavaSystem.CurrentTimeMillis())
                            .SetAutoCancel(true);


            var notification = builder.Build();
            manager.Notify(0, notification);
        }
    }
```

ReminderFragment

```
public static void Remind(Activity mActivity, DateTime dateTime, string title, string message, string eventType)
        {

            Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(mActivity, typeof(AlarmReceiver));
            alarmIntent.PutExtra("message", message);
            alarmIntent.PutExtra("title", title);
            alarmIntent.PutExtra("event",eventType);

            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(mActivity, 0, alarmIntent, PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent);
            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)mActivity.GetSystemService(Context.AlarmService);

            //TODO: For demo set after 5 seconds.
            alarmManager.Set(AlarmType.ElapsedRealtime, SystemClock.ElapsedRealtime() + 5 * 1000, pendingIntent);
        }

btnRemind.Click += delegate
                {

                        var msg = "Wish " + Name + "on their " + eventType;
                    Remind(mActivity, DateTime.Now, "Reminder", msg, eventType);
                    Toast.MakeText(mActivity, "Reminder set", ToastLength.Long).Show();

                };
```

Manifest

```
<application android:label="Events" android:icon="@drawable/Icon">

    <receiver android:name=".AlarmReceiver" android:enabled="true">
    </receiver>
  </application>
```

`SplashActivity` is my launcher activity. But the Fragment is shown from another activity called `MainActivity` (Could that be the issue?)
For testing purposes I have enabled the app to show notifications after 5 seconds, but somehow this is not working and the notification does not show up.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Are you registering your broadcast receiver when main activity starts.

Comment: @Ramit thanks for pointing that out. It was a silly  mistake. I FORGOT to register the Receiver. Could you post your answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: I added answer. In addition to this I want to mention that there are other ways to solve your problem (from manifest itself). I am exploring these and will update answer once done, if you get time please also explore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please register receiver on main activity start and unregister on exit.

Comment: I checked other way to solve this (by manifest only code) you are using <receiver android:name=".AlarmReceiver" android:enabled="true">. So please make sure path of your AlarmReceiver file is correct. It is in top level file inside your package otherwise please mention path like .folderName.AlarmReceiver etc...